# setting overflow css property from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

I have a cell in the table with inner div:

```
<td class="source">
  <div class="overflow">
    <a href...>...</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Initially I want to have:

```
td .overflow {      
overflow: hidden;       
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

then in javascript mouseenter handler for the  element:

```
$(this).parents('td').css('overflow', 'visible').css('text-overflow', 'visible')
```

but it doesn't work! nothing happens on hover... why?
When I reverse the code and make the overflow visible at the start then hover does hide it .

thank you

Comment: What is `$(this)` in your code? What, and *where*, are the constraints on the size of the `div`/`td` that results in it/their having an overflow?

Comment: give the `table`'s code too, not only the `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for all parents `TD`, not the `.overflow` element. Try this:

```
$(this).closest('.overflow').css({
    overflow: 'visible',
    textOverflow : 'visible'
});
```

Setting overflow on `TD` does not work in all browsers as expected.

Comment: you should use the object form `textObject` instead of `text-object`, for both consistency and performance reasons.

Comment: thank you for this.. it was obviously a stupid mistake... I have to do this on 'overflow' div, not TD... thanx again!